# i want to add background image with transparent black in relative layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

[image i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPAB.png) but when implementing it it changes to like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDg5i.png) how to fix the layout_height

```
                         <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rel_top"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/lin_detail"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@color/blackTrans80"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">
                             ...
                            </LinearLayout>
                         </RelativeLayout>
```

```
                            val relativeLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rel_top)
                            val thumbnailUrl = comicDetailAPI!!.data.comic_detail.thumbnail

                            setRelativeLayoutBackgroundWithThumbnail(relativeLayout, thumbnailUrl)
```

```
    fun setRelativeLayoutBackgroundWithThumbnail(relativeLayout: RelativeLayout, thumbnailUrl: String) {
        val requestOptions = RequestOptions().centerCrop()

        Glide.with(relativeLayout)
            .load(thumbnailUrl)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(object : SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        relativeLayout.background = resource
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

how to fix the layout_height in relative layout

Comment: You need to this for relative layout :   
android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

Change your Layout height as Odp.

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blackTrans80"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If the 0dp is not working in ReletiveLayout then leave the relative layout height as it is("wrap_content"). And try to change the LinearLayout height 0dp. it will cover the full view that you declare in xml.

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/blackTrans80"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```